# Custom function that runs at a specific time with if & and inbuilt formulas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

```
=IF(AND(NOW() >= rmdate("2020-10-05 01:19:00"),NOW() <= rdate("2020-10-05 01:19:00")), remindercore("test","nine","+9212345678","Farooq Hospital","2020-10-05 23:30:00"),"Pending")
```

I have this function that runs a custom `function remindercore()` when it is specific time. We are adding data through a webhook. So everytime the data is entered. This statement is turned to pending and whenever the specific time occurs, the remidercore function is triggered.

But upon running this I get a `Error loading data` error. But when I click it and hit enter it runs fine. I am automating things and cannot manually hit enter. Any solution to this?

Comment: Hello, Can you explain where you are manually clicking?

Comment: I'm just guessing, but is this a permissions issue, where it works for you, but when triggered by the webhook submitted data, that processing is running under a different account/authorization?

Comment: Can you post the code of your remindercore() function?